# Interpolation Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

My problem is quite a simple one, however I can't seem to find a quick solution.

I would like to interpolate the `y_model` array which is defined at `x_model` coordinates

```
x_model = np. array([ 400.,  425.,  450.,  475.,  500.,  525.,  550.,  575.,  600.,
    625.,  650.,  675.,  700.])
y_model = np.array([  3.30395705e-03,   3.07586379e-03,   2.90207925e-03,
     2.81385536e-03,   2.78152394e-03,   2.14072505e-03,
     1.64075861e-03,   9.81255709e-04,   3.61950352e-04,
     2.15834081e-04,   1.35457654e-04,   8.22104550e-05,
     5.84126935e-05])
```

To new, `x_data` coordinates:

```
x_data = np.array([412., 443., 490., 510., 555., 670.])
```

So i should get a simple 1-dimensional `y-data` array with 6 elements.

I thought of something like this, what's your opinion?

```
from scipy import interpolate

f                  = interpolate.interp1d(x_model, y_model, kind = 'linear')
y_data             = f(x_data)
```

A solution was initially sought based on the primarily raised issue, limiting the question to a linear interpolation.
However, on the course of the discussion some authors rightly pointed out that for such a problem a linear fit wouldn't suffice.

Should a non-linear curve fit be more suitable?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a least-squares fit? It seems like you are looking for more complicated methods than needed for a linear fit.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Did you run into issues?

Comment: no, a least squares could be even better, you're right @allo

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I was looking for the most suitable (mathematically and in terms of programming) approach to solve this apparently simple problem. The linear interpolation could fail in more complex cases, so I got some nice suggestions to make it mathematically more correct

Comment: Suitable for what? Please show a case where current approach fails, and explain what you mean by subtle please. There are no constraints or requirements actually defined in the question. I am therefore voting to close it as asking for an overview of interpolation methods, which is off topic here.

Comment: I added it as answer and linked the documentation, that contains an example for simple interpolation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry, the problem developed by having gotten additional answers. It raised a debate, I'm sorry if I did something wrong. It started as a linear problem, then allo and you rightly pointed out that one should be careful depending on the type of data. as far as I'm concerned, feel free to ditch the question, if that makes you happy. I was just asking for help

Comment: The general topic is interesting to me, and I'd be happy to help. The problem is that I still have literally no idea what you need help with. You show a standard interpolation setup, and do the interpolation correctly. The question seems to boil down to "is this ok?" Without further information, it's hard to help. Could you add more into the question that would help in that regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy has the `interp` function which can do that for you.
You can simply call:

```
y_data = np.interp(x_data,x_model,y_model)
```

The documentation for numpy.interp() you can find here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Comment: super, that gives an equivalent solution to the upper one! I was wondering whether there exist some differences between two approaches. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple methods would be to fit a linear function using least squares.
A simple implementation in numpy is [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html).

You can then use the function `lambda x: m*x+c` with the computed slope `m` and offset `c` to get the `y` value on the line for any `x`.

The numpy documentation contains an example, thats looks almost like the example in your question.

---

My answer above is for the case of linear interpolation.

Regarding your edit from linear to general interpolation: You need to know what function you want to fit. Do you assume your data to be linear?

You can fit a linear function every point set, but the result may be bad, either because there is no linear relationship or because it is noisy data. Without having an idea what function may be appropriate or how large the amount of noise is, you cannot easily fit a function.

The same is true for higher order polynomials, except that you may change the rror from underfitting (linear regression for a function that is not linear) to overfitting (having a too complicated function that matches the given points, but is unsuitable for interpolation).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to inspect your linear regression and tweak it a little bit I would recommend using [scikit-learn's linear regression.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)
The code would be the following:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x_model = np. array([ 400.,  425.,  450.,  475.,  500.,  525.,  550.,  575.,  600.,
    625.,  650.,  675.,  700.])
y_model = np.array([  3.30395705e-03,   3.07586379e-03,   2.90207925e-03,
     2.81385536e-03,   2.78152394e-03,   2.14072505e-03,
     1.64075861e-03,   9.81255709e-04,   3.61950352e-04,
     2.15834081e-04,   1.35457654e-04,   8.22104550e-05,
     5.84126935e-05])

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x_model[:, None], y_model)

x_data = np.array([412., 443., 490., 510., 555., 670.])
y_data = lr.predict(x_data[:, None])
print(y_data)
```

Note that I have to add a dimension to `x` when fitting or predicting because the linear regression expects a 2-D array.

Answer (score 1):

The "scientific" way to do this, is to fit a linear function to the existing datapoints, and calculate the function then on the new x_values. This has multiple advantages, including the possible usage of uncertainties for each datapoint, and also the possibility of error propagation for the interpolated values. (f.e in combination with the very nice package 'uncertainties') You can also easily change your model function, and it does not has to be linear, but can be any function...

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


x_model = np. array([ 400.,  425.,  450.,  475.,  500.,  525.,  550.,  575.,  600., 625.,  650.,  675.,  700.])
y_model = np.array([  3.30395705e-03,   3.07586379e-03,   2.90207925e-03,
     2.81385536e-03,   2.78152394e-03,   2.14072505e-03,
     1.64075861e-03,   9.81255709e-04,   3.61950352e-04,
     2.15834081e-04,   1.35457654e-04,   8.22104550e-05,
     5.84126935e-05])

x_data = np.array([412., 443., 490., 510., 555., 670.])


def linFunc(x, k, d):
    return k*x+d


cop, cov = curve_fit(linFunc, x_model, y_model)


xplot = np.linspace(min(x_model), max(x_model), 10**4)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_model, y_model, 'ro', label = 'original data')
plt.plot(xplot, linFunc(xplot, *cop), 'r--', label = "fittet function")
plt.plot(x_data, linFunc(x_data, *cop), 'bo', label = "interpolated values")

print(linFunc(x_data, *cop))
```

Comment: Also, you can use np.polyfit and scipy.stats.linregress to avoid having to define your own line function.

Comment: just to make it clear: this can only be used if your whole data-set is described by one and the same function!

Comment: On the one hand, you specify no criteria to judge correctness. On the other, your question is specifically about interpolation, not regression or fitting. If recommend editing the question, but at this point it would invalidate all the answers people have spent time writing, so asking another, more specific question would be more appropriate.